# Context value changed when passed out of main.go on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

There's a problem where I don't know why a `context.Context` was changed once I pass it to a different package on Google App Engine.

The following code works fine when running on App Engine:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", myHandler)

    appengine.Main()
}

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    account, err := appengine.ServiceAccount(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[myHandler] error:", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("[myHandler] ServiceAccount:", account)
    }   

    w.Write([]byte("ok"))
}
```

I could retrieve the ServiceAccount successfully when accessing `/`, and everything was good.

However, when I passed the context from `main.go` to another package, the function call didn't work. The following was added to `main.go`:

```golang
import (
    // other stuff
    "github.com/adlerhsieh/q_context/handlers"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", myHandler)

    appengine.Main()
}

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    account, err := appengine.ServiceAccount(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[myHandler] error:", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("[myHandler] ServiceAccount:", account)
    }   

    handlers.AnotherFunc(ctx) // <--- added this

    w.Write([]byte("ok"))
}
```

Another package:

```golang
package handlers

import (
    "log"
    "context"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func AnotherFunc(ctx context.Context) {
    account, err := appengine.ServiceAccount(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[AnotherFunc] error:", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("[AnotherFunc] ServiceAccount:", account)
    }
}
```

When I ran it on App Engine, the log said:

```
2019/09/04 09:36:30 [myHandler] ServiceAccount: myaccount@gmail.com
2019/09/04 09:36:30 [AnotherFunc] error: not an App Engine context
```

The function calls are the same, but just in different packages. I dug in the package itself and found that it uses the key [here](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/internal/api.go#L93) (which leads to [here](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/internal/api.go#L258)) to setup the context. And [here](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/internal/api.go#L253) to check whether that value was setup properly. However, that value seem to be modified/changed so that the second function call couldn't get it. Even if I omitted the first function call and went straight to the second one, it still has the same error.

Any idea why context object was modified when passing to another package?

The following is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: go111
service: default
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 0
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 30

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  login: admin

nobuild_files:
- vendor

env_variables:
  ENV: 'dev'
  GO111MODULE: 'off'
```

[Here is the GitHub repo link](https://github.com/adlerhsieh/q_context).

Thank you!

Comment: Use appengine.Main() in second ```func main()```.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but there’s only one main(). Did you mean in AnotherFunc()? Edit: ah I know what you meant, but it’s actually already included in the “// other stuff” comment. I just didn’t show the whole thing.

Comment: Not!! I known that was two app! Sorry!
In this case,

Comment: Your code in github no match with your description here.

Comment: Probably something was missing during copy/paste. But the problem did persist when the context was passed to the other package. Please suggest based on the code in the repo. Thanks.

Comment: Show the code in `main` that  sets the `ctx` variable for the case that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my code actually worked. It's because of some other operation error.

However, I'll just post the issue that actually caused it so it can help those who have the same issue.

With the new `go111` runtime, it treats packages from non-root directory or its subdirectories as a different type of package. This caused the problem with "not an App Engine context". I'll just call it an "outcast" package for now (cause I'm not entirely sure why's that).

For example:

```
- appengine
  - main.go
  - handlers
    - handlers.go <-- this is a regular package
```

```
- appengine
  - main.go
- handlers
  - handlers.go < -- this is an outcast package
```

An outcast package would have issues handling `context.Context` generated from App Engine, as pointed out in my question.

The mechanism of App Engine knowing that the context is created from App Engine, is using a built-in value that can only be retrieved from its internal package (with an un-exported pointer-string key). When passing the context to an outcast package, we can no longer retrieve the value from the context. It's still a mystery for me that why the value disappeared, but it's probably because of some Go compiling mechanism.

The solution would be moving the `main.go` to the top-level directory in the project, so that there would be no outcast package anywhere.